# Realtime overlay png image (with tansparency) over webcam output to feed to v4L2 loopback virtual video camera

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay, v4l2

I've been struggling with this for a few days and just can't get the final part of the FFmpeg command right. I'd be very grateful for any help please. I have studied similar questions and answers on StackExchange, and have updated the v4L2 driver as suggested:

Uninstall v4l2loopback-dkms and its dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove v4l2loopback-dkms
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install  v4l2loopback-dkms
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and FFmpeg version 3.4.6-0

Using the preliminary commands:

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback  exclusive_caps=1
ls /dev/ | grep video
I get 2 video sources:
video0..........my webcam
video1..........v4L2 loopback virtual camera
```

The following will show my 'Zingari.png' logo in VLC on device video1:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -re -i ~/Desktop/Zingari.png -f v4l2 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p /dev/video1
```

And this one below will overlay Zingari logo over the Scooter video and record the output to a file:

```
ffmpeg -i ~/Desktop/Scooter.mp4 -i ~/Desktop/Zingari.png -filter_complex "overlay" -codec:a copy example_marked.mp4
```

I have tried various ways of combining these commands eg:

```
ffmpeg -i ~/Desktop/Scooter.mp4 -i ~/Desktop/Zingari.png -filter_complex "overlay"  -f v4l2 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p /dev/video1
```

and that is very close, but gives a muxing overhead error and this output:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '~/Desktop/Scooter.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf54.20.4
  Duration: 00:00:16.95, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2040 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1925 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 15 tbn, 15 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, png_pipe, from '~/Desktop/Zingari.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 233x217, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (mpeg4) -> overlay:main
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> overlay:overlay
  overlay -> Stream #0:0 (rawvideo)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, v4l2, to '/dev/video1':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 13824 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbn, 15 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 rawvideo
frame=  252 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:16.80 bitrate=N/A speed=66.4x    
video:28350kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Just to recap: webcam stream /dev/video0 + png => v4L2 stream to /dev/video1

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I see no error. Trying adding -re before each input as in ffmpeg -re -i ~/Desktop/Scooter.mp4 -re -i ~/Desktop/Zingari.png -filter_complex "overlay" -f v4l2 -pix_fmt yuv420p /dev/video1

Comment: Thanks for helping; what I'm aiming at is overlaying the png over the live feed from my webcam though, not the scooter video, which I was using temporarily to try to build up a solution as I learned more about FFmpeg. Sun

Comment: I have tried what you suggested and it did work out OK, so thank you for your advice. I'll now try to change the source to the live feed from my webcam. Progress. Sun

Comment: Thanks for reformatting, I couldn't see how to do that without resubmitting it as another question. Sun

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
Make sure you've installed latest version of v4l2loopback-dkms

Tested using Ubuntu 18.04 and FFmpeg version 3.4.6-0

Using the preliminary commands: 
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=1

ls /dev/ | grep video, shows 2 video sources: 
video0..........my webcam 
video1..........v4L2 loopback virtual camera

Below will overlay Zingari logo over webcam video and stream as video1 to VLC AND to Chrome and Jitsi-Meet video conference in a tab.

ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -i ~/Desktop/Zingari-Transparent-Cropped-D.png -filter_complex "overlay" -f v4l2 -pix_fmt yuv420p /dev/video1

The addition of -re as kindly suggested above seemed to be necessary when using the video file.mp4 input and the image.png, but not the webcam. I tried removing the -re to test the effect; it still worked OK and also reduced the latency.

Comment: `-re` should not be used with the webcam input as you observed. Files only. Not live inputs. Properly [formatting](https://superuser.com/editing-help#code) your question and answer will improve readability greatly.